# Tangent calculation looks wrong

Tags: graphics, shader, vulkan, renderer

I'm loading an .obj file and I'm trying to manually calculate the tangents in order to use them to implement normal mapping. I'm using [LearnOpenGL.com](https://learnopengl.com/Advanced-Lighting/Normal-Mapping) as a reference.

The tangents look wrong to me (the normals transformed to world space using the TBN matrix also look wrong). I didn't expect these sudden changes in the tangent direction that can be seen in various places in the screenshot (especially where the adjacent triangles are roughly in the same plane).
[image: Sponza tangents]

The code that calculates the tangents is

```
for (uint32_t i = 3; i < newMesh.indices.size(); i += 3) {
    uint32_t vertex0Index = newMesh.indices[i - 3];
    uint32_t vertex1Index = newMesh.indices[i - 2];
    uint32_t vertex2Index = newMesh.indices[i - 1];

    auto& v0 = newMesh.vertices[vertex0Index];
    auto& v1 = newMesh.vertices[vertex1Index];
    auto& v2 = newMesh.vertices[vertex2Index];

    glm::vec3 tangent(0.0f);
    glm::vec3 edge1 = v1.position - v0.position;
    glm::vec3 edge2 = v2.position - v0.position;
    glm::vec2 deltaUV1 = v1.uv - v0.uv;
    glm::vec2 deltaUV2 = v2.uv - v0.uv;

    float f;
    float denominator = deltaUV1.x * deltaUV2.y - deltaUV2.x * deltaUV1.y;
    if (std::fabs(denominator) <= std::numeric_limits<float>::epsilon()) {
        tangent = v1.position - v2.position;
    }
    else {
        f = 1.0f / denominator;

        tangent.x = f * (deltaUV2.y * edge1.x - deltaUV1.y * edge2.x);
        tangent.y = f * (deltaUV2.y * edge1.y - deltaUV1.y * edge2.y);
        tangent.z = f * (deltaUV2.y * edge1.z - deltaUV1.y * edge2.z);
    }

    assert(!isnan(tangent.z));

    // Accumulate tangent
    v0.tangent += tangent;
    v1.tangent += tangent;
    v2.tangent += tangent;
}
```

I wasn't sure how to deal with the case when `denominator`  is 0 to avoid division by 0. Trying to handle those cases doesn't seem to make a noticeable difference.

This is the shader code that outputs the tangent vector as the output color:

Vertex shader:

```
layout (location = 4) out vec3 tangent;

...
// Build TBN matrix
vec3 T = normalize(normalMatrix * vTangent);
vec3 N = normalize(normalMatrix * vNormal);
// Make sure the vectors are still orthogonal
T = normalize(T - N * dot(T, N));
vec3 B = normalize(cross(N, T));
// Handedness
if (dot(cross(N, T), B) < 0.0f) {
    T = T * -1.0f;
}
...
tangent = T;
```

Fragment shader:

```
layout (location = 4) in vec3 tangent;
...
outFragColor = vec4(tangent, 1.0f);
```

Any suggestions on what I might be doing wrong or where to look?